# sIFR replaces Text in one single line in Opera

Tags: sifr, opera, sifr3

I tested my site in different browsers now (IE, FF, Safari, Chrome) and so far sIFR works fine. But when it comes to Opera the text, which goes over more than one line, is rendered in one single line without breaks.

Can this be solve, so that it's rendered correctly?

Comment: it's Opera Version 10.10

Comment: could you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

ok this is strange. I got it to work now, but I didn't change my sIFR config or anything else related to the sIFR implementation.

What I did was change my main-HTML file. I switched `<span>` with `<p>` tags and accordingly moved some markup statements in the according css file like

```
#div {
   ... markup that already was there and works in the other browsers
}
```

to

```
#div p {
   ... most of the markup here now
}
```

Well, although I'm glad that it works now. I really want to know what the issue behind this could be!?

Answer (score 0):

Logically it sounds like Opera isn't handling text inside `span`s correctly as it's only wrapping the text encapsulated inside `p` tags (and for non-paragraphed text, it's handling it as nowrap...?)

That seems like a bizarre behaviour just for text, however the introduction of Flash, and Opera's handling of that, has always been a little strange IMO. Perhaps it's something to do with the standard defined at the top of your document. Are you using strict or transitional? Or perhaps it's a quirksmode thing? Could it be something to do with `overflow` (:visible) and the way Opera's interpreting the newly-replaced sIFR text as just a layer with 'something' in as opposed to text?

Sorry this isn't so much of an answer as a series of suppositions, but I can't add this as a comment as I don't have a high enough rep yet on SO.

You may get some inspiration from reading docs like http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html on quirks mode, I've found Opera to be a bit quirky itself in the past. Sometimes standards compliant can be *too* standards compliant ;-)